# Weird text rendering with jsPDF from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, jspdf, html2pdf

I'm trying to convert a piece of HTML to PDF, I can't show all the PDF here, but this is an example of my issue

[image]

the above image converts a simple

```
<p style="border: 1px solid red">qualquerrererrererer</p>
```

to PDF

The text is being rendered below the line height, even with no css styling the element

I'm developing with nextJS, react and typescript, this is the piece of code that convert the HTML to PDF

```
function print () {
        const input = document.getElementById('divToPrint');
        // eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
        const pdf = new jsPDF({
            orientation: 'portrait',
            unit: 'px',
            format: [input.getBoundingClientRect().width, input.getBoundingClientRect().height]
        });
        pdf.html(input, {
            callback: () => {
                pdf.deletePage(2);
                pdf.save('test.pdf');
            },
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: input.getBoundingClientRect().width
        });
    }
```

Anyone have ever had the same issue? I've searched a lot, but didn't find anyone with the same problem.

I already tryied to set, `line-height` on css, `vertical-align`, remove margins, paddings, tryied to change the jsPDF properties from `unit` `px` to `pt`, setting different sizes on format, setting format to `a4`, nothing seens to work, event setting the `line-height` higher, sets the text inside the box, but still have a huge gap above it

## My temporary solution

I had wrap every text with a `span` with `position: relative; top: -/*half of the size of the font*/`

Comment: Do you mean below the line height?

Comment: @John yees, thank you, I'll ajust the question